# Two subdomains with same layout and website hierarchy but different content. How to tell Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content, optimization

I have two subdomains for the same real-estate company. Each domain is targeting a different country.

E.g.

- `country1.example.com`
- `country2.example.com`

Both subdomains have the **same exact styling and hierarchy** *but* **different content**.
How to tell Google not to consider it as duplicated content and not get a penalty?

And what are the best practices to get the best ranking for such scenarios?

Comment: Why are you worried about duplicate content if the content is *different*?  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site) there are issues when the *same* content is available on different URLs.

Comment: because there are pages that contain only the project name and a set of photos for it. so this case could happen and now google will consider it duplicated!

Comment: That particular page is going to be duplicate and Google will choose to index just one of the duplicates?  Will that be a problem?  A page of pictures is unlikely to rank for much of anything in web search.

Comment: So, you mean as long as there is a slight difference between those two websites, Google will not give me a penalty? And I am free to go and publish those websites as they are without adding any extra meta tags or whatever to tell Google anything?

Comment: Google almost never issues website penalties for internally duplicated content. When Google detects duplicate pages within a site, it usually chooses one of the two to index and ignores the other. So your pages that have different content between the two sections shouldn't get hurt by the pages that are the same between the two sections.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site) which has more in depth about it.

Comment: Thank you very much :) :)